# VS 2010 profiler CPU counters

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiler

In the properties windows i have selected "Collect CPU Counters" and moved "L2 misses" to the right column. I ran the CPU sampling for console app. Where can i see this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Collect CPU Counters' option in the Performance Session only applies to 'Instrumentation Mode' as discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385751%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

In Sampling Mode you can sample on a single CPU counter such as L2 misses by changing the sampling event as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182376.aspx).